# IIS 7.5 Warning : Cannot verify access to the path

Tags: iis, windows-7, asp.net, iis-7.5

I'm newbie in IIS 7.5 , Before this I used to run ASP.NET Website under IIS 5 , That was too easy .

I'm trying to run a very simple asp.net website ( just created a new website from VS 2010 targeted in .net 3.5) in IIS 7.5.7600 on windows 7 Ultimate 64 bit .

While adding application , during Test Setting i receive one warning that says :

> The server is configured to use
>   pass-through authentication with a
>   built-in account to access the
>   specified physical path. However, IIS
>   Manager cannot verify whether the
>   built-in account has access. **Make
>   sure that the application pool
>   identity has Read access to the
>   physical path**. If this server is
>   joined to a domain, and the
>   application pool identity is
>   NetworkService or LocalSystem, verify
>   that \$ has
>   Read access to the physical path. Then
>   test these settings again

But I don't know how to make sure application pool identity has read access to the physical path ?

I'm wondering if there is any step by step article or some thing that show me the walk-though for running a simple asp.net website on IIS 7.5?

I appreciate any help .

Answer (score 2):

for the error you are receiving

you'll probably need to look at using a local user account on each system with the same name and password.  When you connect from ServerA to ServerB, which based your description are in a workgroup , having the same user id and password will help get over authentication issues between machines.

Another option would be to look at NULL sessions, which in itself is a security risk. Here is more information on NULL sessions.

http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/a4939515-b651-4ee0-b327-867b31fd8c9a.mspx?mfr=true

I would recommend going the route of using local accounts with the same password.

---

if you still have the message, try this

In ADD VIRTUAL DIRECTORY, select CONNECT AS and enter an administrator and the pass.
Then all should be allowed or enter a user who has full access to the location